# I am trying to make a border around five fill in the blank questions in HTML, how do I make it just surround the words rather than the whole section?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the border not go across the whole horizontal section, but I can't figure it out.

Here's the code I tried:

```
 <section class="info">
  <label for="fname" class="name">Credit Card Number:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br>
<label for="fname" class="name">Expiration Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br>
<label for="fname" class="name">Date of Birth:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<br>
<label for="fname" class="name">Adress:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  <br>
  <label for="fname" class="name">Email:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
</section>
.info {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    display: 
}
```

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/aussieworz83/nedqubg9/4/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the border of the parent element not go across the whole horizontal section

Use `width: fit-content`.

On applying fit-content for the parent width, it's width will take up the maximum width of it's child element

```css
.info {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    width: fit-content;
}

/* Below code is not required, this is only for styling */
/* start */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}


label {
  min-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
/* end */
```

```html
<section class="info wrapper">
  <div>
    <label for="fname" class="name">Credit Card Number:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="fname" class="name">Expiration Date:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="fname">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="fname" class="name">Date of Birth:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name1" name="fname">
  </div>
    <div>
    <label for="fname" class="name">Adress:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="fname" class="name">Email:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname3" name="fname">
  </div>
</section>
```